# Centos Stream vs Centos linux?

Tags: centos-8

I have been using centos as my desktop environment, now there are two versions of centos available for download. Centos stream vs centos linux.

As per google centos stream is basically used for testing but then why is there centos linux.
I want to know this because i want to install the one which will be more stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the only difference is centos-stream is rolling release versus centos 8.2.2004 point release. Rolling release updates applications and the kernel as they are available versus on big release like say Fedora 33 (since that's a big one lately.)
You can turn your regular centos into a rolling release at any time.